# designing cool UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I wanted to have a nice looking table view, which is less boring, not just the standard one. I will display an image as well as a detail text on each cell... any tips on making it less boring? I was thinking of eliminating the borders on the table view, but how can I do that? Also I wanted to have the Image displayed larger with rounded corners

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following tutorials to have a good tableview.

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

http://icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/

Comment: last link is dead

Answer (score -2):

You probably already know about this sort of thing, but you can embed frames in each table cell, which will allow you to change the locations and properties of different elements in the cells.

A friend of mine was able to change the color of the table cells as well using a loop. e.g. the first is blue, second is red, third is green, and fourth is blue, etc.

Hopefully that helps a bit. Good luck!